# Rotate image by random amount on hover in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm building a photo gallery and trying to make the images rotate when hovered over but I'm having trouble passing values from TypeScript into the CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="back">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981359-219d6364c9c8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583585635793-0e1894c169bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=913&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583531172005-814191b8b6c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583426573939-97d09302d76a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=968&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583532452513-a02186582ccd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583445013765-46c20c4a6772?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583531172005-814191b8b6c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583426573939-97d09302d76a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=968&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583532452513-a02186582ccd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583445013765-46c20c4a6772?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981359-219d6364c9c8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583585635793-0e1894c169bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=913&q=80" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583532452513-a02186582ccd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583445013765-46c20c4a6772?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583531172005-814191b8b6c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583426573939-97d09302d76a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=968&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981359-219d6364c9c8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583585635793-0e1894c169bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=913&q=80" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583426573939-97d09302d76a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=968&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981359-219d6364c9c8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2100&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583585635793-0e1894c169bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=913&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583532452513-a02186582ccd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583445013765-46c20c4a6772?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583531172005-814191b8b6c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80" style="width:100%">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.back {
  background-color: var(--grey1);
  padding-bottom: 28px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 14px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 14px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 28px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;

  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;

  transition: all 500ms;

  box-shadow: rgba(3, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.15rem 0.5rem, rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.075rem 0.175rem;

}

.column img:hover {
    box-shadow: rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.35em 1.175em, rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.08) 0px 0.175em 0.5em;
    transform: scale(1.025);

 }

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**TypeScript**

```
export class PhotosComponent implements OnInit {

  random = Math.random(); //Trying to pass this into CSS

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I have tried using [ngStyle] to modify it in the HTML but as far as I know the rotation is not able to be changed in this way.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/6okvLu7a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
//in .ts
rotate(){
   return {transform:'rotate('+Math.random()*360+'deg)',
           'transform-origin':'50% 50%'}
}
//in .html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" [ngStyle]="style" 
  (mouseout)="style=null" 
  (mouseover)="style=random()">
```

or

```
random(){
  return Math.random()*360+'deg'
}

//and in .html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" [ngStyle]="{transform:'rotate('+rotation+')'}"
  (mouseout)="rotation=null" 
  (mouseover)="rotation=random()">
```

If you want to change the "rotation" of an image. But Really you should put your code in a *ngFor (or in two) to make the things more confortable -it's not practice- and use an array of "rotations" or similar

Answer (score 0):

try this code in typescript to link it with css class:

const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
element.classList.add("myClass");

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of how to get the random number into the CSS class

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the CSS code is static so you cannot change values in your CSS during runtime, unless you would update the CSS on the fly.
But if you would define the images in CSS and assign classes to them ('class1', 'class2', etc), you would be able to switch them with a random number that computes to your defined classes. Generate a random number 0-10 and concatenate with 'class'.

And you need to hook it up to the mouseover event, with @HostListener I quess.